# passing $scope to the services in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to pass the $scope to services and store it in the services so other controllers can use it.

For my application user input the UserName and through ng-model i am passing it back to controller, but it is very limited to that particular controller and other controller can't access that scope.

I have also looked into $rootScope but it is not the answer.

Is there a way that i can store this username into services and pass it to the API in services so i don't have to worry about it. Currently i am doing something similar to this post
[Pass scope to Service on AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18934154/pass-scope-to-service-on-angularjs)

This what i have so far in my services

```
(function() {
    var gitHubApiFactory = function($http) {

        var urlBase = "https://api.github.com";
        var factory = {};


        factory.getUserName = function(userName) {
            return $http.get(urlBase + "/users/" + userName);
        };
        factory.getUserRepo = function(userName) {
            return $http.get(urlBase + "/users/" + userName + "/repos");
        };
        factory.getRepoLang = function(userName,repoName) {
            return $http.get(urlBase + "/repos/" + userName + "/" +repoName);
        };
        return factory;
    };

    gitHubApiFactory.$inject = ['$http'];

    angular.module('gitHubApp').factory('gitHubApiFactory',gitHubApiFactory);

}());
```

I don't want to pass parameter(userName) everytime, instead just pass it in services.

Thanks you all for the awesome support with angularjs.

Answer (score 1):

Services in AngularJS are singletons, so it is not safe to pass name in this service if you have different user names. It is better to pass all needed parameters in functions.

If you want to pass username as constant, you can create angular *value* or *constant* and inject it in your gitHubApiFactory.

Create value:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.value('clientId', 'a12345654321x');
```

Create constant:

```
myApp.constant('planetName', 'Greasy Giant');
```

More info about values and constants:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

Comment: Hi taras, yes you are right ,i want to store the userName after it is authenticated with github, and as services are already loaded it will loss its objective of being singleton.then how can i store userName after it is authenticated so every other controllers can see it ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Model shared between your controllers and your service that stores the state of your application, including the userName :

```
angular.module('gitHubApp').factory('gitHubModel', function() {
    var model = {
        userName: '';
    };

    return model;
});
```

You can then inject it wherever you want to share the userName. If you only need to store value and not behavior, you might use the simpler value recipe :

```
angular.module('gitHubApp').value('gitHubModel', { userName: ''});
```

You can find more informations there :

- [Providers (angularjs.org)](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/docs/guide/providers)
- [Factory recipe (learn-angular.org)](http://www.learn-angular.org/#!/lessons/the-factory-recipe)
- [Value recipe (learn-angular.org)](http://www.learn-angular.org/#!/lessons/the-value-recipe)

Comment: hi hugo, thanks for the answer, do you mind explaining more on this ? or pointing me to the right resources where i can learn more? It would be nice if you are able to show working example or something. Sorry very new to Angualarjs. Thanks

Comment: I added some link to the documentation. I would also recommend to read about angular's dependency injection as well

Answer (score 1):

You can share your state between other controllers by using the service as you prefer:

**JavaScript:**

```
(function(angular) {

    function gitHubApiFactory($http) {

        var urlBase = "https://api.github.com/";
        var factory = {
            userName: '',
            repoName: '',
            authToken: ''
        };

        function onAuthSuccess(data) {
            // do something in here to persist user auth
            // follow api instructions on what is returned in the response
            factory.authToken = data.authToken;
        }

        factory.getUserName = function() {
            // on success, onAuthSuccess function is called with the response
            $http.get(urlBase + "/users/" + this.userName, onAuthSuccess);
            return urlBase + this.userName;
        };
        factory.getUserRepo = function() {
            //$http.get(urlBase + "/users/" + this.userName + "/repos");
            return urlBase + this.repoName;
        };
        factory.getRepoLang = function() {
            // $http.get(urlBase + "/repos/" + this.userName + "/" + this.repoName);
        };
        return factory;
    }
    gitHubApiFactory.$inject = ['$http'];

    function HubLandingPageController($scope, gitHubApiFactory) {
        // first controller will set the model
        $scope.apiModel = gitHubApiFactory;
    }
    HubLandingPageController.$inject = ['$scope', 'gitHubApiFactory'];

    // yet another controller to demo sharing of the factory state
    function FooterController($scope, gitHubApiFactory) {
        $scope.model = gitHubApiFactory;
    }
    FooterController.$inject = ['$scope', 'gitHubApiFactory'];

    angular.module('gitHubApp', [])
        .factory('gitHubApiFactory', gitHubApiFactory)
        .controller('HubLandingPageController', HubLandingPageController)
        .controller('FooterController', FooterController);

}(angular));
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="HubLandingPageController">
    <p>
        <label>What's your github name:
            <input ng-model="apiModel.userName">
        </label>
    </p>
    <label>And the repo you'd like to load:
        <input ng-model="apiModel.repoName">
    </label>
</div>

<div ng-controller="FooterController">
    <p ng-bind="model.getUserRepo()"></p>
    <p ng-bind="model.getUserName()"></p>
</div>
```

Full code example in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bvOWUS?p=preview)

Comment: Hi leon great answer, very nice, but i want to store it after it gets authenticated with github and as @taras pointed out in the answer below services are singleton so is it worth doing this way then ? Thanks

Comment: Hi leon, i have a very interesting problem with your approach, if the link opens in the new window it can not find the userName and throws error in the console.

Comment: @GeekOnGadgets interesting, I tried opening it in other windows and browsers and I don't get the error. (I'm using chrome/firefox).

About the auth, you can also store it in the service model after you successfully get the tokens from github. Alternatively you could use a cookie + ng-cookies - but I'm not versed on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is what you want but you should, declare userName as factory attributes. And define once the userName and after in your service call the userName attribute.